# side bar with multiple collapsible sub menu in side bar wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two toggle buttons which I am used to making to the collapsable sidebar sub-menu option. I want to display both collapsed initially. when of them is pressed it shout expand and when the other submenu is clicked the first one should collapse and the other one should get open.

```
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Regular" Foreground="{StaticResource SupremeFontColor}" Margin="6,2,6,0"
                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}" Content="Report Group" ToolTip="Report Group" x:Name="reportToggleButton"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="reportToggleButton_Click">
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Grid  Height="60" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=reportToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Fail Reports." Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="30">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SupremeprimaryDarkBlue}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Other Reports." Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="30">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SupremeprimaryDarkBlue}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                                
                                <!--Sales Report-->
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Regular" Foreground="{StaticResource SupremeFontColor}"  Margin="6,2,6,0"
                                        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily}" Content="Sales Report" ToolTip="Sales Report"  x:Name="salesToggleButton"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="salesToggleButton_Click">
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Grid  Height="60" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=salesToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Daily Course Summary" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="30">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SupremeprimaryDarkBlue}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Finalize Event Payment Report" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="30">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="white" />
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SupremeprimaryDarkBlue}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first clean-up your mess at least a little:

```
<!--I used StackPanel, but it can be any container you have-->
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myTextbox">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>

                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="myToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,2,6,0"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>


                <ToggleButton Content="Report Group" ToolTip="Report Group" x:Name="reportToggleButton" Click="reportToggleButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource myToggleButton}"/>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=reportToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Fail Reports."   Style="{StaticResource myTextbox}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Other Reports." Style="{StaticResource myTextbox}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Sales Report-->
                <ToggleButton Content="Sales Report" ToolTip="Sales Report"  x:Name="salesToggleButton" Click="salesToggleButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource myToggleButton}"/>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=salesToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Daily Course Summary" Style="{StaticResource myTextbox}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Finalize Event Payment Report" Style="{StaticResource myTextbox}"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
```

And after would add something like this in your event handlers:

```
        private void reportToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            salesToggleButton.IsChecked = !(sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked;
        }

        private void salesToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            reportToggleButton.IsChecked = !(sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked;
        }
```

However I would recommend you to learn how to use standard components (maybe MenuItem or TreeItem would work for you) before considering creating something like that.

Comment: it's not working. it throws an error "The name reportToggleButton does not exist in the current context." can you please explain the solution theoretically

Comment: I assume that you added the handlers manually to some other class. You can try to delete handlers you have and add new ones by doubleclicking your togglebuttons in the designer window.  "reportToggleButton" and  "salesToggleButton" should be automatically created by VS in the same context with "reportToggleButton_Click" and "salesToggleButton_Click" unless you manually changed something. The code I provided works, I have tested it by temporary adding to one of the pages of my app.